# multirow's content not pushing the height

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to realize a table with some cells which are on multiple rows.
Thats fine so far but the there is the problem, that when the content of the multirow becomes bigger than the summed one on the single row cells, it will not push the "super-row" but overlapping down to the next few rows. See picture for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Dies ist eine Caption}
    \label{tbl:test}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlX}
        \hline
        {\#}                       & Beschreibung des Szenarios                                         & {\#\#} & Problemstellungen                                                                               \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{PS1}  & \multirow{3}{\hsize}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, }
                                                                                                    & PS1.1  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS1.2  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS1.3  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{PS2}  & \multirow{3}{\hsize}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.}
                                                                                                    & PS2.1  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS2.2  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS2.3  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\ \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It seems like the small rows on the right side defines how height the left multicol becomes. How can I fix that?

Comment: it's a documented limitation of the package, just use `\\[20pt]` or whatever is needed so the rows have enough space to hold the spanning entry

Comment: Where should I use that?

Comment: at the end of the table rows where you have `\\ ` use `\\[2cm]` instead then the multirow will not be bigger than the (enlarged) row it is spanning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the natural height of the rows being spanned is too small, `\multirow` does not stretch them, so you need o increase their size, for example by using the optional argument to `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Dies ist eine Caption}
    \label{tbl:test}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXlX}
        \hline
        {\#}                       & Beschreibung des Szenarios                                         & {\#\#} & Problemstellungen                                                                               \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{PS1}  & \multirow{3}{\hsize}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, }
                                                                                                    & PS1.1  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[3.2cm] \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS1.2  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[3.2cm] \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS1.3  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[3.2cm] \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{PS2}  & \multirow{3}{\hsize}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.}
                                                                                                    & PS2.1  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[1.6cm] \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS2.2  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[1.6cm] \cline{3-4}
                                   &                                                                    & PS2.3  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aen \\[1.6cm] \hline

    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```